# How to install custom package from a zip file (MVC) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'll try to not steal your time and be as short as possible..

1. Say i have this structure in my Laravel app (it's just a REST Api, sort of):

   - RootFolder/app/models
   - RootFolder/app/Http/controllers
   - RootFolder/app/Http/routes.php
   - RootFolder/public

(these are the folders i use at most part)

2. Now, say i have a zipped file with the following structure:

   - RootFolder/app/models/myNewModelToImport.php
   - RootFolder/app/Http/controllers/myNewControllerToImport.php
   - RootFolder/public/someFilesAndFoldersToImport
   - myNewDataBaseToUploadOnServer.sql

Now, what i want from laravel is to automatically extract these files to the corresponding locations and upload myNewDataBaseToUploadOnServer.sql database to my private server...
Overall, i would like to install this "package" from a zip file, just like you would install plugins for WordPress..

Thanks for your time

Comment: Ehmm, to be honest i havent tried so many options because im not sure if this even exists...Has anyone done it so far?

I took a look at this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages
, but it looked too complicated for a "simple" task like uploading and extracting files...
I also thought of writing my own functions to automate this process (extract and copy files and upload database to my server), but then again, i believe there is something already done so i dont waste my time and yaddayadda (im really in a rush..i have a day or two only, andy im quite busy to write it myself....)